# Given $x^T(A^TMA)x\leq \theta x^TMx$, obtain a tight bound for $y^T([A^TMA]\otimes [A^TMA])y$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, matrix-norms

Assume that for matrices, $M,A$ where $M$ is positive definite and $0<\theta<1$ the inequality $x^T(A^TMA)x\leq \theta x^TMx$ holds for any vector $x$. I want to obtain a bound for $y^T(A^TMA\otimes A^TMA)y$ where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. My hope is that the bound is of the form $y^T(A^TMA\otimes A^TMA)y\leq \theta^2 y^T(M\otimes M)y$.

My attempt was to obtain a direct upper bound using matrix norms (induced by the Euclidean norm as $\|M\|=\max_{\|x\|=1} \|Mx\|$) and the Rayleigh inequality.

Concretelly, we know that $\|M^{1/2}A\|\leq \sqrt{\theta}\|M^{1/2}\|$. Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
&y^T(A^TMA\otimes A^TMA)y = \| (M^{1/2}A\otimes M^{1/2}A)y \|^2\leq \|M^{1/2}A\|^4\|y\|^2
 \\& \leq\theta^2\|M^{1/2}\|^4\|y\|^2 = \theta^2\|M\|^2\|y\|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, using the Rayleigh inequality I get $\|y\|^2\leq y^T(M\otimes M)y/\lambda_{\min}(M)^2$. Thus, instead of a multiplicative factor of $\theta^2$ I obtain $(\|M\|/\lambda_{\min}(M))^2\theta^2$.

However, $(\|M\|/\lambda_{\min}(M))^2\geq 1$. I wonder if its possible to obtain a tighter bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for any two positive definite matrices $X$ and $Y$, we have $X\preceq Y$ if and only if $\rho(Y^{-1}X)\le1$. Therefore
\begin{align}
X\preceq Y
&\Leftrightarrow \rho(Y^{-1}X)\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow \rho(Y^{-1}X)^2\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow \rho\left((Y^{-1}X)\otimes(Y^{-1}X)\right)\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow \rho\left((Y\otimes Y)^{-1}(X\otimes X)\right)\le1\\
&\Leftrightarrow Y\otimes Y\preceq X\otimes X.\\
\end{align}
Now put $X=A^TMA$ and $Y=\theta M$ and the result follows.

Comment: Is $\rho(\bullet)$ a matrix norm? Thanks!

Comment: It's the standard notation for spectral radius.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is it then. Only one more thing. Do you have a some canonical reference where I should be able to find the first fact you mentioned? ($X\leq Y$ iif $\rho(Y^{-1}X)\leq 1$)

Comment: I think it's covered in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* for instance. Anyway this is an easy fact: $X\preceq Y$ iff $Y^{-1/2}XY^{-1/2}\preceq I$ iff $\rho(Y^{-1}X)=\rho(Y^{-1/2}XY^{-1/2})\le1$.

Comment: I was looking in Horn, but I cannot find it. Anyway, I see that showing that is easy. Thanks!!

Comment: If anyone reads this in the future, the result is in Horn in theorem 7.7.3-(a)